# Scrapy XPath spider not working correctly

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am new to using Scrapy and XPath. I have coded a spider using XPath. It is retrieving data but the data is all messed up. What's wrong with the code? Most of the fields seem to return something but the data is in the wrong column. And is all messed up. Title doesn't show up in 'Title' column and etc.

Exporting the data to a csv file.

```
import scrapy

class suumotest(scrapy.Spider):
name="newselector"

start_urls = [
    'https://suumo.jp/jj/chintai/ichiran/FR301FC005/?tc=0401303&tc=0401304&ar=020&bs=040&pn=1'

]

def parse(self, response):
    #for following property link
    for href in response.xpath('//a[@class="js-cassetLinkHref"]//@href').extract():
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href),
                             callback=self.parse_info)

    #following pagination links 

#defining parser to extract data    
def parse_info(self, response):
    def extract_with_xpath(query):
        return response.xpath(query).extract(' ').strip()

    yield {
        'Title':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/h1/text()'),

        'Rent':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[1]/span/text() | /html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[2]/span/text()'),

        'Floor Details':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div[1]/text()|/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/text()'),

        'Prop Address':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/div[1]/text()'),

        #Beginning Of Property Description
        'Property_ Floor Details':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/text()'),

        'Property_ Construction':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()'),

        'Property_ Story':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/text()'),

        'Property_ Construction Date':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()'),

        'Property_ Insurance':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/text()'),

        'Property_ Parking Lot':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()'),

        'Property_ Moving In':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/text()'),

        'Property_ Transaction Type':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/text()'),

        'Property_ Conditions':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]'),

        'Property_ Handling Store Property Code':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/text()'),

        'Property_ Sumo Property Code':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/text()'),

        'Property_ Total Number Of Houses':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/text()'),

        'Property_ Acting As A Guarantor':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/ul/li/text()'),

        'Property_ Area Information':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[1]/ul/text()'),
        #Property Description End
        #Handling Store Information
        'Handling Store_ Name':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[7]/div/div/p[1]/a/img/text()'),

        'Handling Store_ Contact':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[7]/div/div/p[2]/span[1]/text()'),

        'Handling Store_ Address':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[7]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/text()'),

        'Handling Store_ Opening Hours':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[7]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/text()'),

        'Handling Store_ Closed':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[7]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/text()'),

        'Handling Store_ License Number':extract_with_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/div[7]/div/div/div/ul/li[4]/text()')



    }
```

Comment: What does "all messed up" mean? May we see an example of the target HTML and the output you are getting?

Comment: here is the target page [link](https://suumo.jp/chintai/fukushima/sc_koriyama/bc_100080784877/)

Comment: And by messed up i mean Like The Handle Store Details i.e. all columns are showing up in the propety_ Parking Lot column. 
SOrry Don't know how to show the image.

Comment: @halfer here is the data [pic](http://s1070.photobucket.com/user/farooqbassam/media/a02b8b65-2075-45a4-b0ea-448a9c42dedb_zpsdnpmzkuk.png.html)

Comment: Just to be sure: open a new excel file, go to data - import from text. Select your file and select proper encoding, set comma as delimiter and finish. Excel doesn't always properly open a CSV file when you directly open it. Also linebreaks may mess up your import.